# Use VBA to split a string based on set number of characters

Tags: string, vba, excel

I've been using VBA for about a year now and am still learning what it can do. I have a csv file that needs to be altered in data arrangement to be imported into a software. Up until now I have been fine. But apparently one particular column being imported is running into an issue.

The software is only importing the first 15 characters of the data in the column. The people I am working with would like the data split, with the first 15 chars in the appropriate column and the overflow in a secondary column. I have done some research, and came up with only two options. Use the text to column function or use the split string function. The problem I see with the split string is that I need a delimiter but I need to use the fact that I have to split between char 15 and 16 since there is no recurring delimiter in each data point. Which leaves me with text to column which allows for fixed width. But I have a run into another issue. Char 16 could be a space. I test ran the text to column with the char 16 space and the function dropped the spaces, which are necessary for the importing.

I am at a loss. Is there a way to split a string between char 15 & 16 and maintain any spaces occurring at char 16?

The VBA coding is in an Excel 2007 workbook.

For the sake of showing some of the code not that it has much bearing on my current situation.

```
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
'Insert headers
Sheets(2).Cells(1, 1).Value = "Company"
Sheets(2).Cells(1, 2).Value = "Division"
Sheets(2).Cells(1, 3).Value = "Style" 
Sheets(2).Cells(1, 4).Value = "Label" 

Do While Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1) <> ""  'Insert data
Sheets(2).Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = "LP"
Sheets(2).Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3).Value
Sheets(2).Cells(i + 1, 3).Value = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 30).Value 'Needs first 15 char
'Sheets(2).Cells(i + 1, 4).Value = 'currently blank 'Needs char 16 and beyond
i= i + 1
Loop
```

Comment: Does `Sheets(1).Cells(i, 30).Value` contain the string value that you want to manipulate? If all you require is string manipulation, look here for the VBA `Mid` function: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05e63829(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Yes. And I looked. Thank you. I will test that out now. Hopefully it will maintain leading spaces.

Comment: Just checked. It didn't keep the leading spaces. I will try to research if there is a way to manipulate it to maintain char 16+ space(s)

Comment: `Mid` doesn't trim strings. When you debug the code and look at `Sheets(1).Cells(i, 30).Value`, can you see the spaces you require?

Comment: I tested it.... Inserted "abcdefghijklmno    a" (without quotes, obv) into (1,1) and used... `Sub Test() Sheets(1).Cells(2, 2).Value = Mid(Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value, 1, 15) Sheets(1).Cells(2, 4).Value = Mid(Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value, 16) End Sub` the data has 4 spaces then a.

Comment: Ok, don't know why but the spaces are there. Maybe I was just that blind.... possible... I wear glasses. THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!!!!!!!!!!! You just saved me. I have been trying to resolve this issue for 3 flippin' days!

Comment: Oh... so figured out why I didn't see leading spaces. Apparently, it dropped spaces if the trailing character is a numeric rather than an alpha. EX: "abcdefghijklmno 1" versus "abcdefghijklmno a" unless I format the column as text rather than format as number. Which I will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the `Mid` function

```
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
'Insert headers
Sheets(2).Cells(1, 1).Value = "Company"
Sheets(2).Cells(1, 2).Value = "Division"
Sheets(2).Cells(1, 3).Value = "Style" 
Sheets(2).Cells(1, 4).Value = "Label" 

Do While Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1) <> ""  'Insert data
Sheets(2).Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = "LP"
Sheets(2).Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3).Value
Sheets(2).Cells(i + 1, 3).Value = Mid(Sheets(1).Cells(i, 30).Value, 1, 15) 'Needs first 15 char
Sheets(2).Cells(i + 1, 4).Value = Mid(Sheets(1).Cells(i, 30).Value, 16) 'currently blank 'Needs char 16 and beyond
i= i + 1
Loop
```

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't keep char 16 space. But this function definitely helped a future issue I was seeing.. Text to column had to use desto columns next to each other and one of my conversions had the two desto columns separated by two other columns. This resolves that issue. Just need to find a way to keep spaces found at char 16.